# Multer give undefined for req.file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multer

I'm make api to upload files using node js.

i using multer for handle `multipart/form-data`
but when i `console.log(req.file)` it appears undefined

**Route**

```
const uploadController = require('../controller/upload.server.controller');
const multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

/**
 * Routes
 */
module.exports = function (app) {
  app
    .route('/api/upload')
    .post(upload.single('image'), uploadController.upload);
};
```

**Controller**

```
exports.upload = async function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.file);
};
```

**my request with postman**

[image: request with postman]

Comment: Did you select the value of `image` as an actual file in postman?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.post('/api/upload', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.file);
})
```

Comment: still undefined

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31000105)

Comment: @mjk Wrong answers are still classified as "answers" for the purposes of the Low-quality answers queue. If you believe an answer is wrong, you are allowed to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `req.file` as per the docs source: [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Answer (score 0):

```
// init
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

// "images" are the folder name
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: (req, file, cb) => {
     cb(null, 'images');
   },
});
// put this to config the multer
app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage }).single('image'));
// this is for serving file staticly with "path" module 
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
```

Also make sure you write `enctype=multipart/form-data` in the `form` tag not in the `input` tag AND
add `type=file` attribute in the `input` tag

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered similar problem. Everytime I restart my server postman provided req.file gives undefined. I thought maybe I habe made a bug but I couldn't figure out what was wrong.

Then I tried creating a new request in postman and when I requested req.file works perfectly. I am trying to figure out what is wrong with Postman or am I making a mistake while sending a request.

Comment: This posted response is not really an answer to the question but rather more like "Yup, I also have the same issue". It is more suitable as a comment on the question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33311848)

Answer (score 0):

I happened to had restarted postman, and apparently that corrupted the file I was sending. I wasted 1 hour of my life I'm not getting back...

Changing the file could work :D

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34018402)